# Append value to an entity's property Azure Table Storage

Tags: php, azure

I want to append a value to an existing property in Azure Table Storage using the PHP SDK of Azure. For example:

`PartitionKey: PartitionValue | RowKey: RowValue | PropertyValue -> Value1`

I want to append `Value2` to `Value1` like this:

`PartitionKey: PartitionValue | RowKey: RowValue | PropertyValue -> Value1:Value2`

Is this possible? And is it possible with the `insertOrMerge` entity of the Azure SDK for PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`updateEntity()`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-table-storage/#update-an-entity) to update a PropertyValue of an entity in your table storage.

E.G.

```
$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);

try {
    $result = $tableRestProxy->getEntity("{table}", "{PartitionKey}", "{RowKey}");
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}

$entity = $result->getEntity();

$entity->setPropertyValue("{PropertyValue}",$entity->getPropertyValue("{PropertyValue}") . " append value");

try {
    $tableRestProxy->updateEntity("{table}", $entity);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```